# Django: How to use AJAX to check if username exists on registration form?

Tags: python, ajax, django

When the user enters a username, I want to check the db if that username already exists and display an error message. How would I do that without refreshing the page? With AJAX?

registration_form.html

```
<div class="container-fluid userformcontainer">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-8 userformdiv">
          <h1 class="title userformtitle">Sign up</h1>
          <form method="POST" class="post-form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% bootstrap_form form %}

              {% buttons %}
              <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default btn-lg userformbutton center-block">Register</button>
              {% endbuttons %}
          </form>
      </div><!--col-->
    </div><!--row-->
</div><!--container-->
```

views.py

```
class UserFormView(View):
  form_class = SignUpForm
  template_name = 'card/registration_form.html'

  def get(self, request):
      form = self.form_class(None)
      return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

  def post(self, request):
      form = self.form_class(request.POST)

      if form.is_valid():
          user = form.save(commit=False)

          username = form.cleaned_data['username']
          user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
          user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']

          if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
              password = form.cleaned_data['password']
              user.set_password(password)
              user.save()

              user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

              if user is not None:

                  if user.is_active:
                      login(request, user)
                      return redirect('card:deck_list')
              else:
                  pass
          else:
              pass
```

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

  class Meta:
      model = User 
      fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']
```

Comment: do you know how to use ajax?

Comment: anyway check that  [link](https://godjango.com/18-basic-ajax/)

Answer (score -1):

You can build your form manually (at least the username field) as per django documentation below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Then you can set "onchange" event for your field to call a javascript fuction that does the AJAX work for you and display the success/failure message in a div tag of your own.

Alternatively, you may want to let a javascript code that runs on page load to attach an "onchange" event to the "username" field based on its name to the same job for you.